# char comparison always false c

Tags: c, char, do-while

I'm trying to do a simple do while loop where any letter other than 'y' or 'n' is invalid and the loop is repeated. Does anyone know why this loop always evaluates to false? Even when a valid character is entered?

```
char user_response[2];

do {
    printf("\nDo you want to process another range (y or n): ");
    scanf("%1s", user_response);
    user_response[0] = tolower(user_response[0]);
}
while (user_response[0] != 'y' || user_response[0] != 'n');

return user_response[0];
```

Comment: If the response is `'y'`, then it is not equal to `'n'` and vice versa.  So, either one or both of your expressions will always be true.

Comment: Your loop tests for an imaginary character that is 'y' and 'n' *at the same time*. It won't accept anything that isn't 'y', and it *also* won't accept anything that isn't 'n'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change || to &&.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use "&&" (and) instead of "||" (or).

You have two tests here: "does the response not equal y", "does the response not equal n". As the response cannot be "y" and "n" at the same time, at least one of those tests will always be true, and by using "or" your while test will always evaluate to true.

Comment: this is more in-depth. But nim answered first. Thanks for the explanation though :)